# Is there a Python Pandas function to rename values in a column, if the values replesent lists with text inside instead of a single word or number?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset with three columns, "year" "category" and "laureate". The column "year" has values of numbers 2019, 2018 etc... the "category" column has values of words - medicine, physics, engineering etc... but the laureates column looks like this:

```
laureates
[{id:something, name:something, surname: something}]
[{id:something, name:something, surname: something}]
[{id:something, name:something, surname: something}]
nan
nan
[{id:something, name:something, surname: something}]
nan
```

How do I rename nan to False and everything else to True and just have boolean values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
df.laureates.fillna(0) != 0
```

output:

```
   laureates
0       True
1       True
2       True
3      False
4      False
5       True
6      False
```

and if that works:

```
df.laureates = df.laureates.fillna(0) != 0
```